# Count the numbers of neighbors in an array with 3D coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, scipy

I have the following problem. I have an an array of 3D coordinates like this:

```
arr = np.array([[21.000,48.000,28.000],[27.000,48.000,31.000],[21.000, 47.000,27.000],[22.000, 21.000, 97.000],[22.000, 20.000, 97.000],[22.000, 20.000, 95.000]])
```

This is only a small extract of the coordinates, because there a millions.
They a all lying in a 3D box. Additionaly I have the miniumum and maxium 
coordinate of the 3D box the coordinates the are lying in:

```
edgeMaxima = [(0,0,0))(40,59,110)]
```

Now i want to calculate the number of neighbors which each coordinate could have in a specific radius and store it in a second array. So lets assume I take the radius 5 i would have 5^3-1 neighbors for most of my coordinates. The edge coordinates of course would have less neigbors. Is there a good way to calculate the numbers of neighbors?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a shortcut, I'd calculate a distance matrix where the distance between each point is entered. This way, for each point you can check its row and filter out all values where the distance is insider your radius.

A hint I can give you `np.cdist` is a very efficient way to calculate the distance of a vector against each row of a matrix.

For filtering, you can again use numpy's vectorized operations e.g. given a numpy row vector `r1` you can filter like `r1[r1<radius]`

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. What's wrong with using `r^3-1` to compute the number of neighbors? (Apart from the fact that it should probably be more like `(2*r+1)^3-1`, assuming Manhattan distance.)

Comment: The problem are the edges. All points in a distance smaller than the radius (5) have less neighbors than the points in the inner of the box.

Comment: I think radius_neighbor_graph from skitlearn could be the right way but i dont know how to be honestly

Comment: I think a way would be to calculate all that edge coordinates of the box with the edge Maxima coordinates with some kind of formula, doing a radius_neighbor_graph with them and to give all other inner coordinates the count of neighbors with the r^3-1 formula. But i dont know how to get these edge coordinates of the box wich lying fall  the radius.

Comment: This looks like a problem for accelerations structures, best would work here are Regular Grids or KD-trees